# typing, audio, and video - problems after upgrading to 15.04

Tags: upgrade, sound, keyboard, video, 15.04

When I attempt to type using any application - gedit or chromium for example - typing is incredibly difficult. There are noticeable lags in the typing - sometimes letters appear normally but every few seconds there is a long pause. After such a pause a word will appear with mistakes - the most frequent mistake is the duplication of a letter - for example tthe instead of the. Another common mistake is letters that appear out of order - for example hte instead of the. Another common mistake is a letter that has been dropped - for example th instead of the.

How can I find out what is causing these pauses? How can I find out why this is affecting the typing? What can I do to remedy the situation? It is making it almost impossible to work.

**EDIT 1:** It appears this is much more serious - it affects video and audio playback as well. The playback 'stutters' - repeats the previous half-second every so often or freezes for a second every so often.

**EDIT 2:** I updated to the binary nVidia drivers (I was using the nouveau driver) and it made no difference.

**EDIT 3:** I updated my BIOS but no difference...

**EDIT 4:** Finally after a long time it turned out that my system monitor, gkrellm, was the culprit. Reinstalling with the system defaults eliminated the problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled 15.04 overtop the existing installation and the problem has gone away. Sadly my display is now set at 1024x768 but I hope a little tweaking will enable my correct video settings.

Comment: This helped because it reinstalled the system defaults for gkrellm

Answer (score -1):

Your problem could be due to various reasons, including but not limited to:

1. something running in the background which uses your CPU or RAM. For this, open a terminal and call `top` or launch **system monitor**. Then open gedit an monitor your CPU and memory consumption. If you see a jump try to find what is causing it.
2. You may need to update your motherboard driver.

Comment: I do use gkrellm as my system monitor and sadly there wasn't any obvious CPU spike that happened :(

I'm not sure what you mean by a 'motherboard driver' - is there some part of the linux kernel that is specific to my motherboard? It is a Dell Vostro 3574.